# при запуск js команду получаю непонятная ошибка на редактор кода VSCode

Tags: javascript

при запуск код получаю такой ошибки, но код правильно написано, код работает. Пожайлуйста памогите
Даже обычная команда не работает

```
const num = 7;
console.log(num);
```

но показан пути (адресс) етсь какой-то незнакомый файл

[Running] node "c:\Users\Shahzad\Desktop\lesson\work\js\tempCodeRunnerFile.js"

Ошибка такой

"node" �� ���� ����७��� ��� ���譥�
��������, �ᯮ��塞�� �ணࠬ��� ��� ������ 䠩���.

Comment: Подробнее. Нужно узнать что именно ты делаешь. Покажи код и команды что ты пишешь в консоль

Comment: @Bakhtiyar Даже обычная команда не работает как это:   
const num = 7;
console.log(num);
патом там указан какой-то незнакомый файл:  
[Running] node "c:\Users\Shahzad\Desktop\lesson\work\js\tempCodeRunnerFile.js"

Comment: Объясни как ты запускаешь свой код. Весь процесс твоих действий. Начиная с открытия vscode

Comment: @Bakhtiyar :). Я начал сделать весь процесс снова, начиная с откртия vscode чтобы тебя написать подробно и ошибка сам себя исчезла, как это решилос я сам незнаю, раньше тоже сколько раз снова и снова запускал, но в этот раз ошибка исчезла :)

Comment: Вангую, что в ошибке написано что-то вроде "node" не является внутренней или внешней командой и т.д. Либо node не был установлен, либо не был прописан в переменной окружения path.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать какой-то из сервисов по определению исходной кодировки. Я попробовал несколько лично с вашей "ошибкой", но не получилось, возможно, из-за того, что я скопировал это с браузера. Мне сказать сложно. Попробуйте так.

Второй вариант, вам нужно поменять кодировку для VS Code в настройках. "Как?" Вы уже сможете найти в интернете

Answer (score 0):

Весь процесс начал снова, начиная открытия vscode и ошибка исчезла.